# Lazy loading Firestore foreign object in Flutter/dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

A lot of my search regarding this topic seems to refer to pagination. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question. If so please help to edit the question so that it makes sense.

What I mean by lazy loading foreign object is the act of loading only the string id or reference path and converting it to a dart object when needed. I'm trying to replicate the implementation of [Ormlite's Foreign Object Fields](https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite.html#Foreign-Objects).

This just seems like a no brainer for complex relationships between collections, because I wouldn't want to read the referenced object if I don't have to. And yet I can't seem to find any way to do this with Firebase easily.

Let's take the following simple data model example:

```
class Parent {
  String id;
  Child child;
}

class Child {
  String id;
  String description = 'child of parent';
  ParentCousin parentCousin;
}

class ParentCousin {
  String id;
  ChildCousin child;
}

class ChildCousin {
  String id;
  String description = 'child of ParentCousin';
}
```

This is just a simple model to demonstrate the necessity for lazy loading objects. You can imagine, if the relationship becomes a bit more complex, loading all the objects upfront will be taxing and unnecessary. Is there a best practice to architect a data model that lazily fetch the referenced object when it is called? What I've thought about so far:

**1. Wrap each referenced data model in a Map<String, Object> objRef**

This way the fetching operation of the parent object will store the id as the key with an initial null object. The object will only be created when the objRef['id'] is referenced.

**2. Wrap each referenced data model in a specialised Reference class**

Similar to the first approach, the reference class will hold an id and the object. The advantage with this approach would mean that the class can have specialised methods defined by the parent on how to fetch its child. See example:

```
class Reference<T> {
  String id;
  T _object; 
  T Function() fetch;

  // Todo Constructor

  T get object => fetch;
}
```

**3. Create placeholder child objects**

In this approach a child object can have the following state:

- Unfetched - the id is filled but other fields have not been populated (not loaded)
- Fetched - the id is filled and other fields are populated (loaded)
- Empty - the id is an empty string (no need to load, there is no child)

I can already feel that this is going to be a lot of boiler plate having to manage the state of the models, not to mention I'm introducing logic into the model itself, which breaks abstraction rules such as MVC or Bloc pattern.

Any existing solution out there or suggestions on best practice?

Comment: Hmm maybe I can use the freezed package sealed class union to manage the state of the model similar to how I would manage bloc states... this way I can delegate the state manage to the bloc... worth investigating further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 years on and there isn't really an easy solution but I'm more familiar with Firestore and NoSql enough to offer solutions for those looking for something like this.

**Caching referenced objects**

1. Cache referenced objects in a map somewhere that is easily accessible such as your App's controller class.
2. Each time the parent object is looked up, join the parent and child by looking up the cached child objects by id. If object exist good, if not, fetch and cache this object so that future look up will already have been buffered.
3. The cache should be short lived to assist in the purpose of joining, because there is no guarantee that the cached objects are the most up to date. So I recommend clearing this cache regularly during the app's life span. The only way to ensure the objects are up to date is to look up the child object each time the child is being referenced - see next solution

**Write a getter to fetch child object**

1. The model will have a getter method that will fetch the object.

Example code:

```
// parent field
String childId;

// parent getter
Future<Child> get child => repo.fetch(childId);
```

2. If you're following any sort of app architecture such as domain driven design, you'll notice that this breaks the rule of separation of concerns. Fetching of the data should be a concern of the Application or Infrastructure layer. To ensure you don't cross this boundary, use an extension to extend your model in the layer of your choice.

Choose an option that best suits your needs. There are pros and cons to both.

The first option is great if your data doesn't change much so caching it is sufficient to keep network calls to a minimum.

The second option is if you care about the validity of the child's data at all time at each reference.

I prefer the first option in most scenarios.